# Why Ctrl+Z invalidates following Enter (\n) in cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n')? (input validation)

Tags: c++, validation

I want to validate a `double` keyboard input:

1. if the input is a `double`, program should continue normally.
2. if the input is anything but a `double`(including `Ctrl+Z`), program should clear the stream state and ignore all remaining input until next `\n` in order to receive new input.

So I wrote this code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    double val{};

    cout << "Please enter a 'double' value:\n";

    while (!(cin>>val))
    {   
        cout << "ERROR: That is not a valid entry. Please try again\n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
    }

    cout << val << "\n\n";

    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

And I have 2 questions: (I want to solve this using only cin and cout please.)

1. When user inputs Ctr+Z and press Enter (which is the same as `'\n'`), `cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');` keeps waiting for a `'\n'` to be entered. Why does this happen, if there is already an Enter (or `\n`) after Ctrl+Z?
2. This code doesnt cover me for an entry like: 98ssssssssss. It will take the 98 value an the sssssssss will stay in the stream. How to improve the code, so that it recognizes it as a bad entry?

Comment: The answer to part 2 is easy, and it's the way you should always do this kind of task. 1) Read the input as a **string**, 2) Check if the contents of the string match your expectations for a double. 3) If so then convert the string to a double, otherwise report an error.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Z is dependent on the machine/platform that you are running on (for ex. on some machines it's Ctrl+D if I'm not mistaken). In general '\n' is not exactly the same thing as the so called "End of Line" for inputs. Even '\n' at the end of your cout statement is better to be replaced with `<<endl;` statement, because the output may be cached for some reason and not printed out immediately.
As john stated, it's better to get your input as a string, then do all the required manipulations over it.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and eof here is Ctrl+Z.

But '\n' is included as an argument of the cin.ignore. It means if you find '\n' you should stop ignoring. Regardless of \n not being 'end of line' it for sure is equal to Enter. Because when I press a letter for example, it recognizes the enter at the end as a \n and stop ignoring.